# Hazelcast client disconnect from whole cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, disconnect

Is there a way for a cluster member to receive a callback when a client disconnects from the cluster (not just a single member).

On the client end the disconnect lifecycle event is only called when the client COMPLETELY disconnects from the cluster, but on the cluster members the 'owner' member appears to get disconnect/connect lifecycle events when there is a socket disconnect/error, so we cannot use the disconnect as an indication of cluster disconnect (it's only temporarily disconnected from this owner member).

We want to use the client disconnect (from the whole cluster) as the trigger to cleanup shared state, in particular, remove entries from an IMap keyed by the client UUID

Answer (score 0):

You can add your listener to the client service.

```
        var hazelcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        hazelcast.getClientService().addClientListener(new ClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void clientConnected(Client client) {
              // TODO
            }

            @Override
            public void clientDisconnected(Client client) {
              // TODO
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have a client listener added to the the config, is that different to adding it with 'getClientService().addClientListener'?

I'm using config.addListenerConfig(listenerConfig);

But the clientDisconnected(Client client) is being called for transient disconnections from the cluster, I think this is for the 'owner' member only, the other cluster members do not get the disconnect and following reconnect. 

So I cannot use the clientDisconnected method since it may be a transient disconnect rather than a full cluster disconnect.

We are using 4.0.3